# App Discovery widget forced hidden

Tags: html, css, iframe, widget

I've just discovered the Widget Builder on Apple's website [[https://widgets.itunes.apple.com/builder/]](https://widgets.itunes.apple.com/builder/%5d) and I'm trying to implement it on my employer's website. It's basically an iframe you host on your website which acts as a widget, it should be the easiest piece of code to implement:

```
<iframe src="https://widgets.itunes.apple.com/widget.html?c=us&brc=FFFFFF&blc=FFFFFF&trc=FFFFFF&tlc=FFFFFF&d=&t=&m=software&e=software,iPadSoftware&w=250&h=300&ids=585027354&wt=discovery&partnerId=&affiliate_id=&at=&ct=" frameborder=0 style="overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;width:250px;height: 300px;border:0px"></iframe>
```

However when placing the code in my html the iframe becomes hidden caused by the following style properties that have been forced into the iframe:

```
display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; opacity: 0 !important;
```

Please note that these style elements weren't present in the original iframe and have somehow been forced into it. I've set up a blank HTML document with no markup whatsoever on my private website [[http://www.vanjaarsvelt.com/app.php]](http://www.vanjaarsvelt.com/app.php%5d) and get the exact same result. Naturally I've Googled this issue but unfortunately to no avail.

I have absolutely no idea what's behind this and how to solve it. Even Apple's documentation [[https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/widgets.html]](https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/widgets.html%5d) doesn't mention anything that is even remotely connected to my problem. If somebody could shed some light on this issue I'm having it would be very appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

How ashamed I am that I didn't think of disabling my Ad blocker extension in Safari. At least it confirms my trust in my coding.